# .NET 5 API update only fields on JSON (Partial Update)

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm building a .NET 5 API restful and I'm facing some issues.

I would like to know if is possible to update only fields that I send on JSON.

e.g.:

JSON on Postman

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Pillar 1"
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Pillar
  {
    [FromRoute]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int IDEvaluationType { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("IDEvaluationType")]
    public EvaluationType EvaluationType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Competence> Competences { get; set; }
  }
```

My APIController

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutPillar(int id, Pillar pillar)
        {
            if (id != pillar.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(pillar).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PillarExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

But when request and debug on VS, all data that I did not send, is setting with null or 0:

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0nnY.png)

And that is updating my database with null values, losing my data that I did not send on json.
I think the Entity is building a query like this:

update Pillar set ID = 14, Name = 'Pillar 123', IsActive = null, IDEvaluationType = null where ID = 14

But what a need is a query like this:

update Pillar set Name = 'Pillar 123' where ID = 14

Is there a way to update only the fields sent on JSON?

Thank you and any questions let me know.

Comment: you need to load Pillar  change fields and do update ...

Comment: The answer is yes, and there are many ways to do so. You need to focus your question and add more information about your tech stack. Look into JSON Patch. as a start.

Comment: also I don't belive if *query like this update Pillar set ID = 14, Name = 'Pillar 123', IsActive = null* is true as `IsActive` is not nullable in model which leads to another problem what if you send `{"id": 14, "name": "Pillar 1", "isActive" : false }` which in your case is same as `{"id": 14, "name": "Pillar 1" }` as default `bool` value is `false`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change only a subset of fields of some particular object, and the operation is known as "patching". For REST services you have to use PATCH instead of PUT, because PUT always means a change of a whole object.

There is an article on Microsoft website, how to implement PATСH requests handling, please have a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I could have commented but I don't have enough privileges.

Yes, it is possible. just create a DTO (data transfer object) to only update certain fields example.

**The Model**

```
<!-- language-all: c# -->

public class PillarNameUpdateDTO {
     [FromRoute]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller**

```
<!-- language-all: c# -->

[HttpPut("{id}/name")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutPillar(int id, PillarNameUpdateDTO dto)
    {
        if (id != dto.ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        // Get the pillar

        var pillar = _context.Pillars.Find(dto.ID);

        if (pillar == null) {
             // throw error,
            return NotFound();
        }

        pillar.Name = dto.Name;
        _context.Update(pillar);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Comment: First, thank you for your support man
Ok, I could create a dto to update the name, but the route should allow any field to be updated. Example: if I send the following json: {"id": 14,  "isActive" : false }, the code must edit only isActive field. Or even if I send the following: {"id": 14, "name": "Pillar 13232", "isActive" : false }. It should update name and isActive field.

any question let me know man

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is like this:

Modify your class or create viewModel:

```
public class Pillar
  {
    [FromRoute]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? IDEvaluationType { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("IDEvaluationType")]
    public EvaluationType EvaluationType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Competence> Competences { get; set; }
  }
```

Try this code

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PutPillar(int id, Pillar pillar)
        {
            if (id != pillar.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var existed = _context.Pillars.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ID=pillar.ID);
            if(pillar.Name!=null) existed.Name=pillar.Name;
            if(pillar.IsActive!=null) existed.IsActive=pillar.IsActive;
            .... and so on

            _context.Entry(existed).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PillarExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

for more complicated models you can init default constructor:

```
public  Pillar()
{
  Name="NotAssigned";
}
```

and use it like this

```
  if(pillar.Name!="NotAssigned") existed.Name=pillar.Name;
```